# ngShow doesn't add ng-show class

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, ng-show, ng-hide

I'm trying to create an animation for an element that is initially hidden by a `ng-show="boolDefaultIsFalse"` attribute.

When I trigger the boolean to be true then the element is shown, but the animation doesn't play.

This is because the element never gets the `ng-show` class. It does start with a `ng-hide` class. But as soon as I show the element then that class is removed and no new ones are added.

Here's a demo of my problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/OkJnxKlp9Ym1mc8CCD05

Anyone any idea how to solve this problem?

---

## Update

I've updated the Plunker.

I added the `ng-class` directive to add the `ng-show` class manually to the `div`. But the animation still doesn't play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you include ngAnimate as a dependency of your module:

```
var app = angular('app', ['ngAnimate']);
```

Angular will automatically add/remove the following CSS classes when the ng-show/ng-hide directives are applied:

> ng-hide-add
>   ng-hide-add-active
>   ng-hide-remove
>   ng-hide-remove-active

To take advantage of this, add your CSS animation styles to these classes.

[Here is an Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/nHynY2s36AA5mW4KL3u6?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

From the angular documents for ng-show:

> The element is shown or hidden by removing or adding the ng-hide CSS class onto the element.

If you want to dynamically add / remove a class, you should use ng-class.

Comment: I was under the impression that `ng-show` automatically added `ng-show` or `ng-hide` to an element. But I guess I was wrong. I updated my Plunker by adding the `ng-class` directive. It now has the `ng-show` class when I press on the link. But the animation still doesn't play

Comment: In that case, it would seem to be an issue with your css.

Comment: Yeh, but it works fine for a `ng-include` (see updated plunker). I don't see why this wouldn't work for a `ng-show`.